# First record of a table by creation date with 2 more conditions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, olap, teradata

I think this is easy to accomplish using OLAP functions, but I still haven't found the winning combination.

My table has the following fields:

- request_id
- corresp_id
- corresp_type
- corresp_status
- create_ts

For every request I have multiple correspondences of different kind and statuses.

I need to find the requests where the first correspondence, 
has corresp_type=3 and corresp_status=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the first row for each request based on create_ts and check if it has corresp_type=3 and corresp_status=4

```
select request_id
from tab
qualify
   row_number() 
   over (partition by request_id
         order by create_ts) = 1 
and corresp_type=3 
and corresp_status=4
```